# React: Help please ==> Why console log is printing two times on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am learning the react and I made a component and inside that I have a on click function and I have a console statement inside that, can anyone explain why it is displaying two times on the render

```
import React from 'react'; 

class App extends React.Component {  
 render() {
        return (
          <>
          <button onClick={console.log("hello")}>Change name</button>
            <h1>hello my name is kushal</h1>
          </>
        )   } }
    
    export default App;
```

below is the screenshot  of the running app for reference

[image]

OK one hello is print because the function onclick function invoke immidetly but why the second one prints

Comment: whenever you passing any handler with () then it will call immediately

Comment: ok one hello is printing immediatly than the second one for what

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use onClick in react.js?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51832797/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found why it prints two times

one hello is printing immediately because of the simple function insted of the es6 function , and the other one is because of the React.strictMode  in the index.js file , i have removed the <React.StrictMode> from index.js and now it is printing only one time,

```
<React.StrictMode>
 <App />
 </React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is also calling the function when the button is rendered. The correct way is to use an arrow function:

```
import React from 'react'; class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={() => console.log("hello")}>Change name</button>
        <h1>hello my name is kushal</h1>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT**: The other console.log() is triggered by something unrelated to the code you shared in your question. As you mentioned in the answer below it was triggered by the `strictMode` you used in your app wrapper:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: one hello is printing because of not using the es6 function than why other one

Comment: Did you try it with the arrow function and it printed it without clicking it?
Check it working here: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-lake-0r9oc?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Although your answer fix a code problem but this is not what OP asked, OP wants to know why second log?

Comment: The first print is unrelated to the code that the OP shared, and also he mentioned why the first print is happening in the answer below

Comment: Included the answer to my post, happy?